# dummy category, include .php file

Tags: plugins

Hello i know this is a dumb question but.... please help me

i've been across google for this and found serval solutions but none that worked for me.
i'm trying to use the PHPExcel lib in a plugin i'm making but i can't get wordpress to find the file.

```
if (! file_exists(SPEE_PLUGIN_DIR . '/lib/PHPExcel.php') ) { echo "nope :("; }
if (! file_exists(CHECKIN_PLUGIN_DIR . '/lib/PHPExcel.php') ) { echo "nope"; }
if(file_exists(plugins_url( '/lib/PHPExcel.php' , __FILE__ ))) {echo "heyo";}
file_exists(dirname( __FILE__ ). '/lib/PHPExcel.php');
```

i've danced around the 2 commands above but both echo's out meaning they can't find the file.
the path is correct, and written in the same capitals as the folder and the file's name.
so what am i doing wrong?
in advance THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it works now, used it months ago. But you can give a try please

```
file_exists(dirname( __FILE__ ). '/lib/PHPExcel.php');
```

Comment: Ty ill try that when i get off work :-)

Comment: nope didn't work :(

Comment: Where are these files in relation to WP? Which folder?

Comment: /wp-content/plugins/time_table/PHPExcel/PHPExcell.php

Comment: What is path & name of file where you use this function. Because in the question you write lib but here there is no "lib" folder. Please clarify.

Comment: Sry wrote the path just before i went to sleep ;-) 
     
/wp-content/plugins/time_table/lib/PHPExcel.php, and phpexcel.php calls a lot of Clases from wp-content/plugins/time_table/lib/PHPExcel/xxx